# SQL Server query result by column to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample code:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b09/5/0)

I need it to result like this:

```
category    outlet1     outlet2     outlet3
Sale        70          20          40
Expense     250         130         200
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: My outlets are not fixed, sorry for not telling this beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can [solve your particular problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b09/9) using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.category,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.outletname = 'Outlet1' THEN t.amt ELSE 0 END) as Outlet1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.outletname = 'Outlet2' THEN t.amt ELSE 0 END) as Outlet2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.outletname = 'Outlet3' THEN t.amt ELSE 0 END) as Outlet3
FROM tblcategory c INNER JOIN
     tbltran t
     ON t.catid = c.id INNER JOIN
     tbloutlet o
     ON o.id = t.outletid
GROUP BY c.category;
```

If the outlet names are not fixed, then you need dynamic SQL.  The problem cannot be solve using a single `SELECT` query.

Comment: Thank you but yes, my outlets are not fixed, can you help me with dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Here with dynamic Outlets http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7b09/25

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(outletname) 
                    from tbloutlet
                    group by outletname
                    order by outletname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT category,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT c.category, o.outletname, SUM(t.amt) as amt
                FROM tblcategory c
                INNER JOIN tbltran t ON t.catid = c.id
                INNER JOIN tbloutlet o ON o.id = t.outletid
                GROUP BY c.category, o.outletname
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amt)
                for outletname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also use the `PIVOT` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT category, outletname, amt
    FROM   tblcategory c
    INNER JOIN tbltran t ON t.catid = c.id
    INNER JOIN tbloutlet o ON o.id = t.outletid
) d
PIVOT
(
     SUM(amt)
     FOR outletname in ([Outlet1] , [Outlet2] , [Outlet3])
) p
```

EDIT : below is the Dynamic SQL version

```
declare @Outlets nvarchar(max),
    @SQL    nvarchar(max)

select  @Outlets = isnull(@Outlets + ',', '') + quotename(outlet)
from    outlet

select  @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT category, outletname, amt
    FROM   tblcategory c
    INNER JOIN tbltran t ON t.catid = c.id
    INNER JOIN tbloutlet o ON o.id = t.outletid
) d
PIVOT
(
     SUM(amt)
     FOR outletname in (' + @Outlets + ')
) p'

print   @SQL  -- print out for verification
exec    sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thank you, but my outlets are not fixed, sorry for not telling this beforehand.

Comment: @Hanzou. i have updated the answer with `Dynamic SQL`  query